# Wait until a webpage finished loading to load the next one in a list

Tags: python, pyqt, webview

I'm using PyQT webView to visit some webpages I have stored on a dictionary the code is something like this:

```
def loadLink(self, url):        
   manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
    request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))        
    self.ui.webView.load(QUrl(visitar))     

def readUnreadLinks(self):
     print "Links to read: " + str(len(self.unreadLinks))
     for link in self.unreadLinks:
         print "link-> " + str(link)
         self.loadLink(link)
```

the problem is it doesn't wait until finished loading the web page and starts loading the next one. I want to load a webpage, wait until it finished loading and then load the next one.

Thanks, this is driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to use [loadFinished](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#loadFinished) signal of yout QWebView control to detect when page loading was finished and trigger loading of the new one. Pls, see if an example below would work for you:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit 

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pages = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.citrix.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://reddit.com']
        self.index = 0

        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView()  
        self.view.connect(self.view, QtCore.SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self.loadFinished)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.pages[self.index]))

    def loadFinished(self, ok):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index < len(self.pages) :
            self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.pages[self.index]))
        else:
            print 'done'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope this helps, regards